# JavaScript - Problem with a COM object with multiple interfaces

Tags: javascript, com

I'm facing a problem that makes me nearly going nuts

I have a javascript in an HTA that must call some COM objects

var com1= new ActiveXObject("progID");

It works fine for nearly all the COM objects, excepted a COM object that implements 2 interfaces IComOne and IComTwo

Is there a way to "cast" the com1 object in order to tell him to use only "IComOne" interface ?

I'd be grateful for any suggestion...

Answer (score 0):

It's been a few years since I last had to play with script and COM, but I thought script could only invoke methods offered up by the IDispatch interface. If your component doesn't support this, you can't use it. It's not like you can call IUnknown.AddRef on any object, for example.

You can get more insight into your component using the OLE/COM object viewer utility of the Windows SDK.

Answer (score 0):

First, if both interfaces are dual then there are multiple implementations of `IDispatch` -- one for each interface, i.e. QI for `IDispatch` on `IComOne` != QI for `IDispatch` on `IComTwo`.

`com1` will point `IDispatch` impl on the default interface (say `IComOne`). One way to get `IDispatch` impl on `IComTwo` is if there is a method on `IComOne` that casts self to `IComTwo` (QI for `IDispatch` on retval happens automagically). So `var com1 = ...` then `var com2 = com1.GetSecondInterface()`.

You could make a "casting helper" to do this too, if "progID" is closed external component.